# Pass cast type arguments to procedure with execute format

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to create multiple views on geospatial data each explicitly casting to the right geometry & I would like to create a helper procedure to do so like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_view_events(
  view_name TEXT, event_type TEXT, geo_type TEXT
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('
     CREATE VIEW %I AS
     SELECT
       id,
       geom::%I AS geom   -- casting required, but how?
     FROM events
     WHERE type = %L
  ', view_name, geo_type, event_type);
END $$;
CALL create_view_events('events_viewX', 'X', GEOMETRY(POINT, 3347));
```

Manually running the `CREATE VIEW` statement with the casting replaced to  `geom::GEOMETRY(POINT, 3347) AS geom` works & running the procedure without the casting also works. However calling through the procedure as-is yields this error I don't know what's going on.

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "GEOMETRY(POINT, 3347)"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function create_view_events(text,text,text) line 7 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: You probably want `CALL create_view_events('events_viewX', 'X', 'GEOMETRY(POINT, 3347)')`.

Comment: Tried with/out quoting the `geo_type` & it yields `"GEOMETRY(POINT, 3347)" does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing the arguments of `GEOMETRY(obj, crs)` type separately to the procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_view_events(
  view_name TEXT, event_type TEXT,
  geo_type TEXT, geo_proj INT
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('
     CREATE VIEW %I AS
     SELECT
       id,
       geom::GEOMETRY(%I, %L) AS geom
     FROM events
     WHERE type = %L
  ', view_name, geo_type, geo_proj, event_type);
END $$;
CALL create_view_events('events_viewX', 'X', 'POINT', 3347);
```

⚠️ But would still like to know how to pass compound types directly.